# Generate various PDFs (probability theory, statistics)

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

How can one most easily generate PDFs (probability density functions) 
with various shapes (say with 1,2,3,... etc. local maximums)?

I mean... let's say I want to generate various continuous functions $f(x)$ such that:

$$f : {\Bbb R} \rightarrow {\Bbb R} $$
$$f(x) \ge 0$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = 1 $$ 
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$

How can I most easily do this?

By "generate" I mean obtain some analytical formulas for $f(x)$.

Comment: What properties do you want these pdfs to have besides for merely being a pdf? There are infinitely many pdfs you could construct, and plenty of well-known ones associated to common continuous distributions you can find anywhere, but for what purpose are you trying to concoct a new pdf from scratch? 

The best way, if you're really interested in generating as many pdfs as you can, is to take pdfs associated with already existing distributions like the normal distribution and then apply transformations to them to produce new ones. I'm not sure why you might want to do this, though.

Comment: @JackCrawford I want to generate a PDF, then take N random variables with that PDF, then visualize the distribution of their `normalized sum` and just visually confirm that the Central Limit Theorem works. Then do it for another N variables but with a different PDF. Just a small experimental app to visualize things.

Comment: I see. There's not really any canonical way of going about producing arbitrary pdfs, but if you were looking to implement this computationally (as a computer program, say), one way you could attempt this is by taking some pre-existing pdfs for known distributions and then transforming them. Say, take $x_1,x_n$ as a bunch of random variables of different known distributions, define their joint pdf to be the product of their individual pdfs, create a new random variable by applying some function to the $x_i$, and then finding the new pdf by the method of distribution functions.

Comment: If you want to generate random values from arbitrary distributions then you could find it easier with quantile (inverse cumulative distribution) functions $q:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ and any weakly increasing function will do. For the central limit theorem, you will want a finite second moment for the distribution

Answer (score 1):

Take any non-negative integrable function $g$.  Compute its integral $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx.$$

Then

$$f=\frac g I$$

is going to be a good pdf.

Comment: Unless $I=0$ of course. Further the OP also asks for $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$.

Comment: @zoli Yeah, well... That's kind of an obvious idea. But $I$ has to be finite. It's not very obvious how to construct such functions $g$. Or...?

Comment: @drhab I think the two limit conditions follow from $I$ being finite. So if I am able to get a function $g$ such that $I$ is finite, and $g$ is always non-negative, then the two limits will be zeros anyway. Right?

Comment: @peter.petrov the limit conditions do not follow from $I$ being finite in general. E.g. let $g$ take value $1$ if $x\in(0,1)$ **and** if $x$ is an integer. The limit conditions do follow from $I$ being finite under e.g. the extra condition that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @drhab Yeah, OK, I am assuming $g$ continuous. I don't mean any "exotic" artificially cooked functions here.

Comment: @peter.petrov Oh, sorry. I overlooked that you mentioned "continuous" in your question already, and the (redundant) limit conditions made me think that this was not the case (I think it is better to leave them out). Btw, in this answer it is only demanded that the function is non-negative and integrable (so could be quite exotic).